# Posting data to CSV on Sharepoint, Onedrive or Dropbox

Tags: powershell

Once I created a simple Powershell GUI that logs visits to our stores and writes events in a local CSV file in our network.

Now I received a request to create similar app for our stores abroad. They're on completely different networks but I'd need a CSV on one location for all of them. I was wondering if there is any way that Powershell posts data (adds a single line) to a file on Sharepoint, Onedrive or Dropbox?

Any advice or example would be appreciated.

Regards

Comment: `Add-PnPFile` will let you upload files to a sharepoint folder, but you cannot easily add single lines, and it's bad for shared usage. For what you describe, maybe add rows to a sharepoint List? https://www.spguides.com/insert-item-to-sharepoint-online-list-using-powershell/ .

Comment: If that is a possibility, maybe a I could use that.
My app writes some data in each line: date, location, user, etc... All that data is written in CSV on my fileshare and each night I import that CSV to Excel spreadsheet that displays monthly visits.
The question is, can I export Sharepoint list to CSV or Excel???

Comment: Yes, sharepoint lists are basically just fancy tables. It should also have an Export-to-Excel/csv button: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/export-to-excel-from-sharepoint-bfb2ea48-6118-4fa9-abb6-cced9424e5d9